# How do I create a balance roll forward in R with a floor (so value doesn't go below 0)

Tags: r

I'm working on some code to create an inventory roll-forward where the customer's end balance can't go below zero but can't think of a way to do it in R:

| ID | BegBal | Purchased | Used | EndBal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 3 | 1 | 2 |
| A | 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| A | 0 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

In a formula it would be:
EndBal = max(BegBal + Purchased - if(BegBal + Purchased > 0 ,1 ,0), 0) ... and then BegBal would be set to the prior EndBal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you can use `pmin`/`pmax`?

Comment: Is `Used` needed? If I do `with(dat, BegBal + Purchased - Used)`, I get your `EndBal`, no adjustment required. If I'm understanding your question, it would help if your data shows conditions that would alter the outcome.

Comment: Why do you need to have a floor of 0? It will automatically have a floor of 0. If its negative, then the usage is wrong since you cant use more than you already have

Comment: I'm trying to understand how to reference the prior record.  I have an initial condition of BegBal=0.  The customer then makes a Purchase.  If the BegBal or Purchase is > 0 then the customer will use a unit so Used = 1.  If their BegBal and Purchase = 0 then Used will be 0.  EndBal then is BegBal + Purchased - Used. Then it moves on to the next day with BegBal = EndBal.

What I'm struggling with is how to recursively reference the prior record and use the value of the prior record + another variable (EndBal and Purchased) to set the value of a 3rd variable (Used) and calculate a 4th (EndBal)

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(EndBal = unlist(
    accumulate2(c(0, Used), Purchased, ~..1 - ..2 + ..3)[-1]),
    BegBal = lag(EndBal, default = 0))

    ID    Purchased  Used EndBal BegBal
  <chr>     <int> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A             3     1      2      0
2 A             0     1      1      2
3 A             0     1      0      1
4 A             0     0      0      0
5 A             2     1      1      0
```

---

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
            Purchased = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L),
            Used = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like it's getting me there.  Can you provide some context on what this portion of your code is doing:  ~..1 - ..2 + ..3)[-1])?

I have an input column for "Purchased" but the rest are meant to be calculated.  "Used" is 1 if BegBal or Purchased > 0 and is otherwise 0.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work (mostly) using a modified version of what Onyambu posted:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                  Purchased = c(3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L)),
                  row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(EndBal = unlist(
    accumulate(Purchased, ~..1 + ..2 - ifelse(..1 + ..2 > 0,1,0))),
    BegBal = lag(EndBal, default = 0))
```

The only issue is that it returns a value for EndBal that is 1 too high for the first record